# C# Switching between two windows forms

Tags: c#, forms, hide, show

I have two forms. In first I have button forwarding me to second form and hiding the first one with this.Hide();

It looks like this:

```
        Form1Streamer f1 = new Form1Streamer();
        f1.Left = this.Left;
        f1.Top = this.Top;
        f1.Size = this.Size;
        f1.Show();
        this.Hide();            
        checkBox1.Checked = false;
```

It also takes it's position but it's not about it.
In second form I have a button which should after clicking Go back to the hidden form and make it visible again, but I can find no solution how to access it's properity. 
I have some ideas but don't really know how to tag it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the reference of the **first** form to the **second** form in order to call any method of first form. Here is a simple Example that will demonstrate.

Below is my first form class

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test_Desktop
{
    public partial class FirstForm : Form
    {
        public FirstForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void showSecondFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SecondForm secondform = new SecondForm(this); //Passing the reference of current form i.e. first form
            secondform.Show();
            this.Hide();       
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my second form class

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test_Desktop
{
    public partial class SecondForm : Form
    {
        private FirstForm firstForm = null;

        public SecondForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        ///
        /// Overriding constructor
        ///
        public SecondForm(FirstForm firstForm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.firstForm = firstForm;
        }

        private void showFirstFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(firstForm!=null)
            {
                firstForm.Show();

                //
                //Do some processing
                //

                this.Dispose(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the reference of hidden form in the second form. For that, change the constructor of Second form like this

```
public Form1Streamer(Form firstform)
{
   InitilizeComponent();
   this.firstForm=firstform;
}

private FirstForm firstForm;
```

Now you can show the First Form using reference `firstForm`

In first form, you need to change this code

```
Form1Streamer f1 = new Form1Streamer();
```

to

```
Form1Streamer f1 = new Form1Streamer(this);
```

Comment: Thanks! I just found it after tags on msdn. Thanks again! :)